# Convert Text Date in R

Tags: r, date

I have data that formats dates like so:

```
Tue Oct 25 2016
Tue Oct 25 2016
Tue Oct 25 2016
Wed Oct 26 2016
Wed Oct 26 2016
Wed Oct 26 2016
```

I would like this to be in a format in which `R` can use it as a date (i.e. `2016-10-25`). Any help?

Comment: check out [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) for examples of working with dates

Comment: `lubridate::mdy(c("Tue Oct 25 2016", "Tue Oct 25 2016", "Tue Oct 25 2016"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: 
I somehow missed that you had the day of the week as well.

This can also be done in base using `as.Date` with the correct formatting string. In this case `%a` would give you the abbreviated day of the week,`%B` will give you the month abbreviation, `%d` will give you the minimum digit day (i.e. 2 instead of 02), and `%Y` will give you the four digit year. In the example these are all separated by a single space, so the format string should reflect that.

```
datesx <- c("Tue Oct 25 2016", "Tue Oct 25 2016", "Wed Oct 26 2016", "Wed Oct 26 2016", "Wed Oct 26 2016", "Wed Oct 26 2016")
as.Date(datesx,format = "%a %B %d %Y")
```

`[1] "2016-10-25" "2016-10-25" "2016-10-26" "2016-10-26" "2016-10-26" "2016-10-26"`

Answer (score 2):

The [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package has `anydate()` which is pretty good and tries a number of different formats.  Here we still need to chop off the (redundant) weekday:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anydate(c("Oct 25 2016", "Oct 25 2016", "Oct 25 2016", 
+          "Oct 26 2016", "Oct 26 2016", "Oct 26 2016"))
[1] "2016-10-25" "2016-10-25" "2016-10-25" 
[4] "2016-10-26" "2016-10-26" "2016-10-26"
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not use extra packages:

```
dates <- c("Tue Oct 25 2016",
       "Tue Oct 25 2016",
       "Tue Oct 25 2016",
       "Wed Oct 26 2016",
       "Wed Oct 26 2016",
       "Wed Oct 26 2016")

# Remove day of the week
dates <- sub("\\w{3} ", "", dates)

# Convert to Date
dates <- as.Date(dates, "%b %d %Y", origin = "1970-01-01")
dates
#[1] "2016-10-25" "2016-10-25" "2016-10-25" "2016-10-26" "2016-10-26" 
# "2016-10-26"
```

Comment: You don't need to modify the original vector.  Just use `"%a %b %d %Y"` for the format.

Comment: "%a %b %d %Y" gives NA's

Comment: `as.Date(dates, "%a %B %d %Y")` is given me NA's (I don't know why)

Comment: Maybe because you've modified `dates` twice already?  Are you re-assigning the original `dates`?

Comment: No, it is because my LOCALE is spanish, `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`  does the job for Ubuntu