# How to convert string "MMM DD YYYY" to date YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: r

I received Excel spreadsheet with text "MMM DD YYYY" for a date column.

Unfortunately, this needs to be dumped into R. Anyone can help convert this to R date?

`excel string Jan 05 2004 to r date 2004-01-05`

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what research have you done? There are lots of posts already on SO on converting dates, and a lot of info that can be gotten from googling something like "r convert text to date," as well as from the docs for basic functions like `as.Date`, which has a similar example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Text Date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653891/convert-text-date-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `as.Date` with the `format` argument

```
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%b %d %Y")
df1$Date
#[1] "2004-01-05" "2004-01-06"
```

---

Or with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy(df1$Date)
```

---

Or automaticaly pick te format with `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(df1$Date)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date = c("Jan 05 2004", "Jan 06 2004"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```